# Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys} If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead

Tags: reactjs

I have this state

```
const [value, setValue] = useState([]) // init with empty array
```

Which I set like this

```
  async function createSalesOrder () {
      const res = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/')
      setValue([...value, res.data])
      return (res)
    }
```

And then I get the Objects are not valid as a React child error

This is how res looks

```
data: {salesOrderId: "9000002031"}
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
headers: {content-length: "29", content-type: "application/json; charset=utf-8"}
config: {url: "http://localhost:5000/", method: "post", headers: {…}, transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), …}
request: XMLHttpRequest {readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, onreadystatechange: ƒ, …}
__proto__: Object
```

And this is how it the values is used in the returned method

```
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>{value.map((item, i) => <p key={i}>{item}</p>)}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
```

Comment: The problem seems to be on render method. Can you show how it uses the `value` state to render in the `return` of the component.

Comment: I added the return component to the original question

Answer (score 0):

Your `value` will have object `{salesOrderId: "9000002031"}` inside it so your map function should look something like

```
         <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>{value.map((item, i) => <p key={i}>{item.salesOrderId}</p>)}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to render an Object in the JSX element and JSX only accepts rendering of individual primitives. So even after mapping, you will need to identify the individual primitive to be rendered. Example: {item.salesOrderId}